# Is there a way to write an exponent in a string using python? Not just ^2

Tags: python

I'm just starting to learn python. When I ask for input from the user, can I write an exponent within that? Can I do that aside from "^2"?

Let's say this is my code:

```
float(input("Gravity in m/s^2, 9.8 for Earth, 24 for Jupiter): "))
```

My output would be:

```
Gravity (in m/s^2, 9.8 for Earth, 24 for Jupiter):
```

But I want the "2" to look like an actual exponent. Is that possible?

Comment: Thank you! If I want to use other numbers, do I have to search it up then copy and paste it? Are there other ways?

Comment: Yes I guess so :)

Comment: Oh, okay! Thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text strings are unicode in Python, you can use the character [SUPERSCRIPT TWO](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00B2) directly in a string:

```
float(input(f"Gravity in m/s², 9.8 for Earth, 24 for Jupiter): "))
```

Comment: What does Unicode mean?

Comment: Unicode is a way of representing characters (and a string is a sequence of characters), on the low level characters are just numbers which we decide correspond for a specific character, which character? this is determined by a simple table, one of the most common table, and the one that python uses is Unicode.

Comment: I have so much to learn. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: From what I've understood just now, anything you put into your string will look the same as your output. Is that right?